# Efficient method to identify or skip overlapping records from a large table

Tags: oracle11g

I have a CTE based on a large table (over 3.5 million rows). The CTE contains start and end dates for attendance for a student attending a base (a base is a school or other establishment) during a term. For each student-base-term combination there should usually be only one row. If there is more than one row, the start and end dates should not overlap between rows. If there is a set of rows with overlapping dates, I want to choose the row with the latest updated date. If there is a tie between the latest updated date then I want to choose the row with the highest value of the row ID (this is arbitrary). I have written some code which appears to work. I would like to know if there might be a more efficient way of doing it. I am particularly wondering if the use of OR twice in the WHERE NOT EXISTS clause might slow it down. I know that performance depends on the database characteristics, but if you can think of a different way that might be better, I can test it. This is my sample code with some test data.

```
WITH
attendance_info(att_id,base_id,stud_id,term_id,att_start_date,att_end_date,att_string,last_updt) AS
(
-- Overlapping pair with identical start and end dates. Keep only the one with the latest updated date.
SELECT 11, 101, 20001, 31, TO_DATE('01-APR-2017'), TO_DATE('30-APR-2017'), 'ABC', TO_DATE('31-AUG-2017') FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 12, 101, 20001, 31, TO_DATE('01-APR-2017'), TO_DATE('30-APR-2017'), 'XYZ', TO_DATE('31-OCT-2017') FROM DUAL
--
-- Non-overlapping pair with different last updated dates. Keep them both.
UNION ALL SELECT 13, 102, 20001, 31, TO_DATE('01-APR-2017'), TO_DATE('30-APR-2017'), 'BCD', TO_DATE('31-AUG-2017') FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 14, 102, 20001, 31, TO_DATE('01-MAY-2017'), TO_DATE('30-MAY-2017'), 'RST', TO_DATE('31-OCT-2017') FROM DUAL
--
-- Overlapping pair with different start and end dates. Keep only the one with the latest updated date.
UNION ALL SELECT 15, 101, 20002, 31, TO_DATE('01-APR-2017'), TO_DATE('30-APR-2017'), 'CDE', TO_DATE('31-OCT-2017') FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 16, 101, 20002, 31, TO_DATE('11-APR-2017'), TO_DATE('12-APR-2017'), 'STU', TO_DATE('31-AUG-2017') FROM DUAL
--
-- Overlapping pair with last updated dates the other way around from the above. Keep only the one with the latest updated date.
UNION ALL SELECT 17, 101, 20002, 32, TO_DATE('01-APR-2017'), TO_DATE('30-APR-2017'), 'DEF', TO_DATE('31-AUG-2017') FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 18, 101, 20002, 32, TO_DATE('11-APR-2017'), TO_DATE('12-APR-2017'), 'TUV', TO_DATE('31-OCT-2017') FROM DUAL
--
-- Overlapping triplet. Keep only the one with the latest updated date.
UNION ALL SELECT 19, 101, 20003, 32, TO_DATE('01-APR-2017'), TO_DATE('30-APR-2017'), 'EFG', TO_DATE('31-AUG-2017') FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 20, 101, 20003, 32, TO_DATE('02-APR-2017'), TO_DATE('29-APR-2017'), 'MNO', TO_DATE('31-DEC-2017') FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 21, 101, 20003, 32, TO_DATE('03-APR-2017'), TO_DATE('28-APR-2017'), 'UVW', TO_DATE('31-OCT-2017') FROM DUAL
--
-- Overlapping pair plus non-overlapping single record. Keep the one in the pair with the latest updated date and also keep the single record.
UNION ALL SELECT 22, 102, 20003, 32, TO_DATE('01-JUL-2017'), TO_DATE('30-NOV-2017'), 'FGH', TO_DATE('31-AUG-2017') FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 23, 102, 20003, 32, TO_DATE('01-APR-2017'), TO_DATE('01-JUL-2017'), 'NOP', TO_DATE('31-DEC-2017') FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 24, 102, 20003, 32, TO_DATE('29-MAR-2017'), TO_DATE('31-MAR-2017'), 'VWX', TO_DATE('31-JUL-2017') FROM DUAL
--
-- Overlapping pair with same updated date. Keep the one with the highest value of att_id (arbitrary choice).
UNION ALL SELECT 25, 102, 20003, 31, TO_DATE('01-JUL-2017'), TO_DATE('30-NOV-2017'), 'GHI', TO_DATE('31-AUG-2017') FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 26, 102, 20003, 31, TO_DATE('01-APR-2017'), TO_DATE('01-JUL-2017'), 'OPQ', TO_DATE('31-AUG-2017') FROM DUAL
),
attendance_info_unique AS
(
SELECT ai1.*
FROM attendance_info ai1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (
  SELECT NULL FROM attendance_info ai2 WHERE
    1=1
    AND ai1.base_id = ai2.base_id
    AND ai1.stud_id = ai2.stud_id
    AND ai1.term_id = ai2.term_id
    AND (ai1.att_start_date BETWEEN ai2.att_start_date AND ai2.att_end_date OR ai2.att_start_date BETWEEN ai1.att_start_date AND ai1.att_end_date)
    AND (ai1.last_updt < ai2.last_updt OR (ai1.last_updt = ai2.last_updt AND ai1.att_id < ai2.att_id))
  )
)
SELECT * from attendance_info_unique
```